# Yii SQL Profiling of AJAX calls

Tags: php, database, amazon-web-services, yii, profiling

Yii offers a setting that profiles all the SQL calls with the execution time of each (CProfileLogRoute). Except it does not work for ajax calls. How can I access this data?

I am trying to find the bottleneck of an ajax call that opens up a login popup...

On a similar note, does the execution time shown in CProfileLogRoute includes the network trip to the SQL server if any? My database is hosted by Amazon's RDS, and I want to know if that's where the bottleneck is (it seems fine locally).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extend [CFileLogRoute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileLogRoute) in the manner proposed below and enable it in application's configuration like this:

```
'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'ProfileLogRoute',
            'levels' => "profile"
        )
    )
)
```

In this case all profiled queries will be written to a log file located in `protected/runtime` directory (overriding of `processLogs` method is implemented likewise summary report of [CProfileWebRoute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CProfileLogRoute/)...unfortunately `CProfileWebRoute` is derived from [CWebLogRoute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebLogRoute)):

```
<?php  
class ProfileLogRoute extends CFileLogRoute
{
    protected function processLogs($logs)
    {
        $logFile=$this->getLogPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->getLogFile();
        if(@filesize($logFile)>$this->getMaxFileSize()*1024)
            $this->rotateFiles();
        $fp=@fopen($logFile,'a');
        @flock($fp,LOCK_EX);

        $profileStack = array();
        $profileResults = array();
        foreach ($logs as $log)
        {
            if ($log[1] === CLogger::LEVEL_PROFILE)
            {
                $message = $log[0];
                if (!strncasecmp($message, 'begin:', 6))
                {
                    $log[0] = substr($message,6);
                    $profileStack[] = $log;
                }
                else if(!strncasecmp($message, 'end:', 4))
                {
                    $token = substr($message,4);
                    if(($last = array_pop($profileStack)) !== null && $last[0] === $token)
                    {
                        $info = array(
                            'delta' => $log[3] - $last[3],
                            'category' => $last[2],
                            'time' => $last[3]
                        );
                        $this->aggregateResult($token, $info, $profileResults);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','CProfileLogRoute found a mismatching code block "{token}". Make sure the calls to Yii::beginProfile() and Yii::endProfile() be properly nested.',
                            array('{token}'=>$token)));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                @fwrite($fp,$this->formatLogMessage($log[0],$log[1],$log[2],$log[3]));
            }
        }

        if (!empty($profileResults))
        {
            $now = microtime(true);
            while(($last = array_pop($profileStack)) !== null)
            {
                $info = array(
                    'delta' => $now - $last[3],
                    'category' => $last[2],
                    'time' => $last[3]
                );
                $token = $last[0];
                $this->aggregateResult($token, $info, $profileResults);
            }

            $entries = array_values($profileResults);
            $func = create_function('$a,$b','return $a["total"]<$b["total"]?1:0;');
            usort($entries, $func);
            foreach ($entries as $entry)
            {
                $message = sprintf("Min: % 11.8f    Max: % 11.8f    Total: % 11.8f    Calls: % 3d    %s", $entry['min'], $entry['max'], $entry['total'], $entry['calls'], $entry['token']);
                @fwrite($fp, $this->formatLogMessage($message, CLogger::LEVEL_PROFILE, $entry['category'], $entry['time']));
            }
        }

        @flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
        @fclose($fp);
    }

    protected function aggregateResult($token, $info, &$results)
    {
        if (isset($results[$token]))
        {
            if ($info['delta'] < $results[$token]['min'])
                $results[$token]['min'] = $info['delta'];
            else if($info['delta'] > $results[$token]['max'])
                $results[$token]['max'] = $info['delta'];
            $results[$token]['calls']++;
            $results[$token]['total'] += $info['delta'];
            return;
        }

        $results[$token] = array(
            'token' => $token,
            'calls' => 1,
            'min' => $info['delta'],
            'max' => $info['delta'],
            'total' => $info['delta'],
            'category' => $info['category'],
            'time' => $info['time']
        );
    }
}
```

If you want to know how Yii measures a time of SQL execution you can look at the source code of [CDbCommand](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/db/CDbCommand.php) class - `queryInternal` method, to be more precise. Profiling is between `Yii::beginProfile('system.db.CDbCommand.query...')` and `Yii::endProfile('system.db.CDbCommand.query...')` calls. As you can see both these calls are within the same method, as the result the time of profiling doesn't include a network transfer. Probably, the issue is that your remote database server runs under huge load.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of the CProfileLogRoute class called **ignoreAjaxInFireBug** which defaults to "true" by setting it to **false** you can get your profiling info on ajax requests.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebLogRoute#ignoreAjaxInFireBug-detail

```
'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
                    array(
                        'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute',
                        'ignoreAjaxInFireBug'=>false,
                        'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, info, profile',
                    ),
        ),
```

I don't believe ou need to use firebug for that work (it's kind of a misnomer). If you do however, just download firefox and install firebug and then your problem is still solved.